# lerna + webpack + babel-loader issue

Tags: node.js, webpack, lerna

Here's where the issue is recreated:

https://github.com/reggi/webpack-lerna-babel-loader-issue

Goal: I'm trying to build `./packages/usage/index.js` with webpack.

- I have 4 packages `alpha`, `beta`, `gamma`, `usage`.
- `alpha`, `beta`, `gamma` are not using babel and should just be consumed using index.js
- `usage` is using babel and should be converted using `babel-loader` then the traversal should contunue

When I try and compile `babel` is oddly being request for the other deps.

```
$ lerna bootstrap
Lerna v2.0.0-beta.20
Linking all dependencies
Successfully bootstrapped 4 packages.
$ cd packages/usage
$ npm run webpack

> @reggi/usage@1.0.0 webpack /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/webpack-issue/packages/usage
> webpack

Hash: 27e6d9d1d4147417b516
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 429ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  2.11 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 3 hidden modules

ERROR in ../alpha/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel' in /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/webpack-issue/packages/alpha
 @ ../alpha/index.js 1:11-33
```

And with `{ exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/ }` enabled I get this.

```
$ npm run webpack

> @reggi/usage@1.0.0 webpack /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/webpack-issue/packages/usage
> webpack

Hash: 99d08ad8b664833bba1c
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 401ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  2.25 kB       0  [emitted]  main
    + 4 hidden modules

ERROR in ../alpha/~/@reggi/beta/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel' in /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/webpack-issue/packages/alpha/node_modules/@reggi/beta
 @ ../alpha/~/@reggi/beta/index.js 1:17-82
```

### Types of bundles

**Without `babel-loader` excluding `node_modules`**

https://github.com/reggi/webpack-lerna-babel-loader-issue/blob/master/packages/usage/bundle-without-exclude.js#L70

> Cannot find module \"@reggi/beta\"

**With `babel-loader` excluding `node_modules`**

https://github.com/reggi/webpack-lerna-babel-loader-issue/blob/master/packages/usage/bundle-with-exclude.js#L77

> Cannot find module \"/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/webpack-issue/packages/beta\"

**Without `babel-loader` & switching code to `require`**

https://github.com/reggi/webpack-lerna-babel-loader-issue/blob/master/packages/usage/bundle-without-babel.js#L97

> Includes everything perfectly.

Comment: I believe this is specifically an issue with the `babel-loader`.

Comment: Have you tried to edit the path in __package-alpha__ into a relative path? I am pretty sure that you shouldn’t use absolute paths in your packages.

Comment: @PDXIII `lerna` is a tool that auto-generates that file. I cannot change it.

Comment: i have created a lerna webpack project [here](https://github.com/hannadrehman/react-monorepo) do check it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One nice thing about using Lerna is you can pull `devDependencies` up to the repo root to factor them out of the individual packages.  This can significantly improve bootstrap time if `devDependencies` are used in many packages.  It can *also*, in this case, help you avoid this strange babel behavior.

If you move the `devDependencies` from `packages/usage` up to the root:

```
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index d3728db..e9b313b 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -1,5 +1,8 @@
 {
   "devDependencies": {
-    "lerna": "2.0.0-beta.20"
+    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
+    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
+    "lerna": "2.0.0-beta.20",
+    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
   }
 }
diff --git a/packages/usage/package.json b/packages/usage/package.json
index 7186ddf..387ddc4 100644
--- a/packages/usage/package.json
+++ b/packages/usage/package.json
@@ -17,10 +17,5 @@
     "presets": [
       "es2015"
     ]
-  },
-  "devDependencies": {
-    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
-    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
-    "webpack": "^1.13.1"
   }
 }
```

Then re-run `npm install` at your repo root.  After that your `npm run webpack` in `packages/usage` should succeed.

Note also that with Lerna you can simplify your workflow here using `lerna run webpack`.

Comment: This is a great solution. However, I'm in a little bind about changing everything because I have an `apex` project nested with this `lerna` package. I'd rather the `apex` hooks stay within the project. Is there any way to get this to work without changing the scope?

Comment: Only babel-loader and babel-preset-es2015 must be moved to the root. Webpack should stay in packages/usage.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this error here:

```
ERROR in ../alpha/~/@reggi/beta/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel' in /Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/webpack-issue/packages/alpha/node_modules/@reggi/beta
```

It looks like the problem is finding the babel loader because `require.resolve` isnt going to look in sibling directory node_modules to find it.

Try configuring webpack to tell it where to resolve the babel loader (within the `usage` project):

```
resolveLoader: {
  modulesDirectories: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
  ],
},
```